# WPF: The name <Name> does not exist in namespace <namespace>

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, namespaces

I am trying to build a solution created elsewhere on my system. The XAML files reference a few third party namespaces, several of which give the error in the title. The solution does compile and run despite these issues.

I am using VS 2015 on Windows 7 system. I tried compiling the same solution with VS 2015 on Windows 10 with no problem. Having said that I do not believe the issue has anything to do with the OS as I am fairly certain that when I started this exercise, I did not see this issue. I believe it crept in at some point along the way as I was investigating other issues.

Below are the namespaces for which I had issues.

```
    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:ToggleSwitch="clr-namespace:ToggleSwitch;assembly=ToggleSwitch"
```

I was able to work around the issue for MahApps.Metro and ToggleSwitch by uninstalling the packages and reinstalling from NuGet, but I should not have to do this. I have not found a workaround for taskbar. Apparently it is obsolete so I cannot install/uninstall it from NuGet. However, I have the DLL so I would think I should be okay.

There are other postings that are somewhat similar where rebuilds or changing build types have resolved this issue but none of these worked for me. I have also tried using VS 2013 (which is what was used to build the solution originally).

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the code that's using `Name`? Perhaps try using `x:Name` instead of `Name`, if the problem occurs on an attribute rather than an element.

Comment: In the case of MahApps.Metro, the first error is on the standard first line. That is <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="CRMConnector.MainWindow". The "Controls:MetroWindow is indicated as not being found.

Comment: Is there definitely a class called `MetroWindow` in the `MahApps.Metro.Controls` namespace of the `MahApps.Metro.dll` assembly?

Comment: Yes, see [link](http://mahapps.com/controls/metro-window.html). Also looking in the object browser you can find MahApps.Metro-->MahApps.Metro.Controls-->MetroWindow. As I mentioned this worked without this error on another system and it compiles and runs just fine on my development system. It is as if something is corrupt somewhere. Rebooting does not help. Does anyone know the search order for for assemblies used for XAML files? It is as if it is different than for compiles.

Comment: As I mentioned simply uninstalling and reinstalling MahApps.Metro clear its errors.

Comment: If you're concerned that it's loading the wrong assembly, you could try adding more information to the clr-include directive to ensure it's loading the correct DLL. Also, look in the debugger's output window and see what DLL(s) are loading.

Comment: Also, you say the solution runs so this isn't a compile error. Is it an exception? What is the stack trace and type of the exception?

Comment: The assemblies being loaded are the correct ones according to the Output window. The solution builds and runs without errors. If I then go and view a XAML file, errors show up in the XAML file as well as in the Error window. If I then compile again I continue to see the errors in the Error window, though the build still succeeds.

Comment: Are you building windows apps using shared projects? Are both parent projects set up with the correct references?

Comment: There are no shared projects. Only the one project with the issue references the packages that VS is complaining about.